# Moving set bits to the end of 64bits integer

Tags: c++, algorithm, bit-manipulation

I am working on a function that takes a 64bits integer as parameter and returns a 64bits integer with all set bits at the end.

```
01011001 -> 00001111   // examples
00010100 -> 00000011
```

I first thought about the following algorithm:

```
nb_ones = countSetBit(x)
int64 res = 1
for i from 1 to nb_ones+1:
    res |= (1 << i)
```

Here `countSetBit` is the one [defined here](https://chessprogramming.wikispaces.com/Population+Count)

Is there something more straightforward ? I am working in C++

Comment: There's another one for counting bits https://tekpool.wordpress.com/2006/09/25/bit-count-parallel-counting-mit-hakmem/

Comment: use a table to map `countSetBit` is a very straightforward way

Answer (score 4, accepted):

countSetBit is probably something that's optimized for your platform already.

To set a given number of ones at the end, just go to the next power of two and subtract one.

```
nb_ones = countSetBit(x)
int64 res = nb_ones == 64 ? -1 : ((1 << nb_ones) - 1);
```

**Edit:** Nice non-branching solution from MSalters' comment:

```
int64_t res = ((1^(nb_ones>>6))<<nb_ones)-1;
```

(the 6th bit in nb_ones is one if-and-only-if nb_ones==64)

The background for the undefined behavior for << 64 is probably that the corresponding native operation might only use the bits of the argument needed for the maximum reasonable shift value, and handling this on the C++ side would add overhead.

Comment: What about the case where `x == (int64)-1` ? Because `1 << 64` would trigger undefined behavior

Comment: Yup, like that (have an upvote), but you do need to check for the edge case `-1`.

Comment: Thanks, fixed O:)

Comment: There's a non-branching solution : `int64_t res = ((1^(nb_ones>>6))<<nb_ones)-1;` - the 6th bit in `nb_ones` is one if-and-only-if `nb_ones==64`.

Answer (score 3):

You can avoid the loop:

```
const auto nb_ones = countSetBit(x)
if (nb_ones == 64) {
    return -1; // 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF;
} else {
    return (1u << nb_ones) - 1;
}
```

Comment: ͏+͏1͏. Out of interest, do you really find `0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF` clearer than `-1`? Or am I an odd cat?

Answer (score 3):

Counting all bits is a bit overkill as most CPU's have an efficient test against zero.

So, what we do is use that as the exit condition:

```
output = 0;
while (input != 0) {
  if (input & 1) output = (output<<1)+1;
  input >>= 1;
}
```

The loop shifts the input to the right, adding one extra bit to `output`  whenever a bit is shifted out of `input`. Clearly this adds as many bits to `output` as there are in `input` (possibly 0, possibly 64). But the bits in `output` are contiguous as `output` is only shifted when a bit is added.

If your CPU has a bitcount operation, that's going to be faster of course. And if you'd implement this in x86 or ARM assembly, you'd use the fact that `input&1` is the same bit that is shifted out by `>>=1`.

Comment: You're late to the party but nonetheless this is the best answer. Have an upvote!

Answer (score 2):

Since you have several *efficient* answers, when you actually asked for a *straightforward* one, have a slow-but-conceptually-very-simple answer for variety:

```
uint64_t num(uint64_t x)
{
    // construct a base-2 string
    auto s = std::bitset<64>(x).to_string();
    // sort the 1s to the end
    std::sort(begin(s), end(s));
    // and convert it back to an integer
    return std::bitset<64>(s).to_ulong();
}
```

Comment: This is so nicely written it demonstrated to me that I implemented completely the wrong thing. Have an upvote too.

Comment: I still don't have any intuition about _why_ OP wants these bits there, or what it could be useful for - which is probably why it took me a couple of reads to figure out as well.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do it with just a single loop:

```
std::uint64_t bits_to_end(std::uint64_t n)
{
    std::uint64_t x = 0;

    for(std::uint64_t bit = 0, pos = 0; bit < 64; ++bit)
        if(n & (1ULL << bit))
            x |= (1ULL << pos++);

    return x;
}
```